# How automate using sh scripting

Tags: automation, sh, turbogears2

I'm a beginner with sh scripting and I need some help, can someone help me to convert this command lines extracted from Turbogears page to an sh script, thanks in advance.

```
$ virtualenv --no-site-packages tg2env
$ cd tg2env/
$ source bin/activate
(tg2env)$ pip install tg.devtools
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an editor to create a file with these contents (and let's say it is called `my_first_script.sh`):

```
#!/bin/sh

virtualenv --no-site-packages tg2env
cd tg2env/
source bin/activate
pip install tg.devtools
```

Then execute this from command line to make it executable:

```
chmod 755 my_first_script.sh
```